# how to install mongodb compass from stable version onto windows 10

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I was following an exercise and wanted to install MongoDB Compas (1.19.6(Stable)).  I successfully downloaded he .dmg file and extracted the file using 7-zip but when I go into the folder, I can't find a exe or instructions on how to run/install compass.   Please help.

I searched the MongoDB site and found the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/install/) but it says nothing about a .dmg file.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: DMG? Is that not MacOS? Please go to the download page and make sure you get the correct installer

Comment: Yep, just checked the downloads page and the default on the dropdown for OS selection is OS X. Click on the dropdown and select Windows 64 bit (7+) and download that instead. It will have an `.msi` extension.

Comment: The default download platform should be selected based on your detected O/S, but the `.dmg` download is definitely for macOS. The Windows download options for Compass include `.exe`, `.zip`, and `.msi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for windows10 installation,Click on the drop-down and select Windows 64 bit (7+) and download that instead. It will have an .exe extension.